DEVISE NoMethodError in Admin::Shop#index (rails 7)
my apologies for all the pictures
I am following a tutorial by Conner Jensen(youtube) on creating an ecommerce platform using rails 7. I have run into a couple of problems whilst following this tutorial and the current one is concerned with the link_to element. The functionality that i am looking forward to seeing is for the "Show Shop Button" ( which will be shown soon) to take to me to the correct partial/view. This is how ConnerJensen solved his problem:
his initial error was like this:

he then fixed his error by doing the following edits to the links that point to "Show Category" in his _category.html.erb file:

the problem is that my files look completely different form his.
for starters, my _shop.html.erb which is supposed to correspond with his _category.html.erb looks like this:

for the sake of comprehension, these are the files that were generated by devise for me:

and this is my index.html.erb for the /admin/shops:

and that is the error message that I get:

WHEN I CHANGE THE PATH IN THE "Show this shop" from admin_shop to @shop, the admin/shops page works, but the individual links point to admin/shops and not to desired page for specific shop :


https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode -- don't use pictures for code or errors.

@dbugger I am new to stack overflow and programming, my apologies for the pictures. I will be sure to edit the question pronto

you can remove all the pictures, just show us your link and your routes. but i assume the fix would be the same: link_to "Show this shop", [:admin, admin_shop]

hard to confirm without seeing the routes and controller def show code.
@shop is probably nil so rails figures if it doesn't have anything to display it sends you to the index.  If the routes are setup correctly, you can use:
admin_shop_path(admin_shop)  Which tells Rails to render /admin/shops/[:shop_id] in a more explicit manner.
